# 16.04 LTS did not load all the way

Tags: 16.04, upgrade

Glad I can ask for help. I very much appreciate Ubuntu. I read one answer which I think might help.

On 10/13/16 I upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04. During the upgrade messages said some packages did not load right (libmetacity, compiz-plugins-default, compiz-core, Oubuntu1, Compiz, metacity-common; there were numbers after each). At the end a message said computer may be inoperable, then the upgrade ended with no cleanup or restart.

My computer is a laptop, Aspire 3620. It was given to me and I think it is 10 years old. It ran slow with 14.04.

I can sign in, then get to the internet by using the terminal. I do not get a desktop, nor can I get to my documents, nor run update manager, so far anyway.

Can I get 16.04 fully installed/running? Thank you for considering this!

Todd

Comment: Besides what may have gone wrong during the upgrade, these are the requirements for Ubuntu, check it out:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

Answer (score 0):

hey just off the top of my head, if you can access the command line you can update from there, use the following commands

$ sudo apt-get install update-manager-core

that should give you the update manager then
i'm guessing your gedit may not also work for file editing, if you can use vi do this

$ sudo vi /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
then change this line "Prompt=lts" to "Prompt=normal" *you can use any other text editor*

then do this

$ sudo do-release-upgrade

let me know what happens

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried the above but could not run the commands due to unmet dependencies. Those were generally the packages that did not load when I first did the upgrade. Any other suggestions? Much appreciated, Todd